# Complex matrix eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a square matrix with complex entries (e.g. a symplectic one). Let this matrix have a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues: does this imply that the corresponding eigenvectors are complex conjugate too?

PS: I know that's a very basic and general question, so suggestions to improve it are welcome too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Take, for instance,$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -1-i \\ 1-i & 1\end{bmatrix},$$whose eigenvalues are $\pm i$. The eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $i$ are the multiples of $(1,-1)$, whereas the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $i$ are the multiples of $(1,i)$.

Comment: Thank you!! Let me ask a thing more: could a pair of complex conjugated eigenvalues have corresponding eigenvectors whose imaginary part have the same sign?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The imaginary part of a complex vector is a real vector. What is the sign of a vector?

Comment: Sorry for the bad phrasing! Suppose there's a 2x2 complex matrix with a pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues (e.g. $e^{±iα}$). Could such eigenvalues have corresponding eigenvectors of the form (e.g.) $(β+iδ, ε-iζ)$ and $(η+iθ, κ-iλ)$ (where $α, β, γ, δ, ε, ζ, η, θ, κ, λ \in \mathbb R$)?

Comment: *Every* vector from $\mathbb C^2$ has that form. Did you mean $[0,\infty)$ instead of $\mathbb R$ perhaps?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Sorry another time. $α, β, γ, δ, ε, ζ, η, θ, κ, λ \in [0, \infty)$

Comment: Take $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2+3 i & -2 i \\ 6+2 i & -2-3 i\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, for instance. Again, its eigenvalues are $\pm i$. An eigenvector corresponding to the eigen value $i$ is $(1,1-i)$ and an eigenvector corresponding to the eigen value $i$ is $(1,2-i)$.